# AngularJS ng-repeat with different objects

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, object

I'm new to AngularJS and have written an app which calls an specific API. It gets an object back like this:

```
posts = [
    posts = [...]
    users = [...]
]
```

That's the HTML template:

```
<div id="{{'post-' + $index}}" ng-repeat="post in posts.posts">
    <article>
       <h1>{{post.user.username}}</h1>
       <span>{{post.date | date: "dd.MM.yy, HH:mm"}}</span>
       <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

I want to show different posts (from the posts object) including the username (which is in the users object). How can I tell Angular that the posts are in the posts object and the proper usernames are in the users object?

Comment: What does a post look like? Are the `posts` and `user` arrays mapped 1-to-1?

Comment: Looks to me like the data you are returning should be formatted better. The way it is now you assume there is a 1 to 1 relationship. if that is the case then you should be able to put them both in the same object.

Answer (score 1):

ngRepeat creates a new scope for each entry. That scope will contain `$index` for the current offset in the array. Since it's a new scope the variable `posts` is now in the `$parent` scope.

Assuming `posts` and `users` contain parallel data and are arrays. You can lookup data in `users` using `$index`.

```
<h1>{{$parent.posts.users[$index].username}}</h1>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the structure of the `posts` and `users` object, it's hard to say exactly, but the general idea is to use the `users` object, with the user_id from the post object, so either something like this:

```
<h1>{{users[post.user.id].username}}</h1>
```

Or like this:

```
<h1>{{getUserNameForPost(post)}}</h1>

$scope.getUserNameForPost = function(post) {
     //find the user based of the post however you want
     user = $scope.users.filter(function(u) { return u.id = post.user });
     return user[0].username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would suggest you change the structure of the returned JSON object, to something similar to the one below:

```
posts = [
    { 
    id : "post id",
    title: "Post title",
    content: "Post content",
    date : "post date",
    user : {
        id: "user id",
        name: "user name"
        }
    },
    ....
    ....
]
```

This should work.